# Using ORs incl. 95%CIs to find pairwise differences

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, categorical-data, confidence-interval, pairwise

I am investigating how students score on a test, based on their experience on the subject. My outcome, test_answer, is binary (0 for a wrong answer, 1 for a correct answer). Experience is a categorical variabel: group 0-3 (0 is no experience, and 3 is the group with the most experience). I have investigated this using a logistic regression model (I’m using Stata):

```
logit test_answer i.experience, or
```

Thus, I’ve got ORs incl. 95% CIs and p-values for all experience-group compared to no experience (group 0 = ref):

- Experience-group 0: ref.
- Experience-group 1: 4.5 (4.1-4.9)
- Experience-group 2: 9.1 (7.4-11.0)
- Experience-group 3: 8.0 (7.1-8.9)

  - All p<0.001

I would like to also compare the groups with each other, and not just with the reference group.
I could use chi^2 Test of Independence to determine whether there is a significant association between reader experience and test-score, and this way see if there is pairwise differences between them.

However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it. I already have ORs incl 95% CIs for the groups, so I think, that I somehow could make use of these to get 95%CIs for the pairwise differences, and from these calculate p-values.
But I am not sure how I would do this. Can any of you guys help me? Or maybe you have an even better/more elegant way?

Additional info: My data format is long, i.e. like this:

```
student_id     experience     test_answer   
1              0              1
1              0              0
1              0              1
...            ...            ...
2              2              0
2              2              1
...            ...            ...
```

Comment: Be aware that your logistic regression model has not accounted for within-subject correlation within each `student_id`. This is a problem. It seems that your research question is, "to determine whether there is a significant association between reader experience and test-score". If this is the case, I'd recommend calculating a total score for each student, and then conduct a linear regression with the total score as the outcome and the level of experience as the exposure (with no experience as the reference group).